# Postresql: changing column data type from text to float/decimal

Tags: sql

I have two columns that I want to change from data type text to float/decimal but the output keeps reading the following:
I was told to use cast but if there is any other way please let me know

`ERROR`:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
SQL state: 22P02

or

`ERROR`:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
SQL state: 22P02

The code I have tried so far are the following:

```
select cast (columnname as decimal)
from tablename
```

and

```
select *
    case when(columnname1 is not null or columnname2 != '')
        then columnname2::double precision
        else 0
    end as column_num
from tablename**
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and what you expect the result to be

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.